# Erro Ao subir container Docker

Tags: php, laravel, docker

Quando dou um docker-compose up, o container sobe normalmente, mas quando acesso o localhost, da erro 500, a pagina nao está funcionando, e no console aparece os seguintes texto de erro. Estou utilizando as imagens do ambientum do codecasts.

```
restapi-app | [19-Mar-2019 11:38:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 15 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/app/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/app/public/index.php on line 24"
restapi-app | 127.0.0.1 -  19/Mar/2019:11:38:15 +0000 "GET /index.php" 500
restapi-app | [19-Mar-2019 11:38:15] WARNING: [pool www] child 15 said into stderr: "NOTICE: PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/app/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/app/public/index.php on line 24"
restapi-app | 2019/03/19 11:38:15 [error] 12#12: *4 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP message: PHP Warning:  require(/var/www/app/public/../vendor/autoload.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/app/public/index.php on line 24
restapi-app | PHP message: PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/app/public/../vendor/autoload.php' (include_path='.:') in /var/www/app/public/index.php on line 24" while reading response header from upstream, client: 172.23.0.1, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://127.0.0.1:9000", host: "localhost"
restapi-app | 172.23.0.1 - - [19/Mar/2019:11:38:15 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 500 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/73.0.3683.75 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

Procurei na internet, e tentei passar permissão total para essas pastas porem sem sucesso. O meu .yaml está da seguinte maneira

```
# v2 syntax
version: '2'

# Named volumes
volumes:
  # MySQL Data
  restapi-mysql-data:
    driver: local

services:
  # MySQL (5.7)
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    container_name: restapi-mysql
    volumes:
      - restapi-mysql-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=restapi
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=restapi
      - MYSQL_USER=restapi
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=restapi

  # PHP (with nginx)
  app:
    image: ambientum/php:7.2-nginx
    container_name: restapi-app
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/app
    ports:
      - "80:8080"
    links:
      - mysql
```

As configurações do .env pro mysql já estão feitas. Alguem tem alguma luz do que pode ser ? PS: é um projeto simples do laravel criado atras do laravel new  crú, nao mexi em nada.

Answer (score 0):

O problema foi resolvido, era problema no meu projeto laravel, alguns arquivos faltando ele n conseguia subir a pagina (: